# Asking for a study leave while keeping my permanent job

Tags: leave-of-absence

I'm an undergraduate student who has a permanent job. As I have more academic work in my final year, I believe it would be better to take time off from my 40 hours per week job at least for one month. I'm not exactly sure how these sorts of things should take place within a workplace. I would like to get back to my job after my stressful time is over in college.

Does my request seem reasonable enough? What are the usual actions that are possible for me to take in my situation?

Comment: In my country, you wont start before completing your final year( though you would have a job offer). Could you explain your situation?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether this sort of requests are too odd. I don't want to terminate my employment.

Comment: This depends on way too many factors to give you an answer. Just ask your manager.

Comment: You can certainly enquire about taking extended leave, but that request may be declined (which is increasingly likely for longer periods of leave), and it would probably be unpaid if it goes beyond how much leave you have. The way that these things should take place in the workplace is that you just speak to your manager about it and take it from there.

Comment: how can you be an undergraduate and have a fulltime job are not the two incompatible

Comment: @Neuromancer I should mention that to my friend who's also doing that that it's not possible. It is possible, you just have to have a very flexible schedule for your job. That friend has already passed his undergraduate and is currently doing the same for his masters. He holds a full time job and is also studying for his masters

Comment: @Neuromancer Many people work full time while finishing their degree. Not everyone can afford to pay for college out-of-pocket.

Comment: @Neuromancer - the current job might not require a college degree for the level that OP is at, but having one can enhance OP's job, leading to better performance reviews, raises and advancement, or possibly a reclassification would kick in upon having completed a degree.

Comment: Are you in Sri Lanka? Please add a country tag, because the majority of answers here are approaching your problem as you were in the US.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the request is reasonable.
However, the reaction always depends on the workplace.

Any corporation (big or small) has policies on how to deal with these issues.
IMHO, what you looking for is an unpaid leave of absence for personal reasons or professional development, depending on if you work in the field of your study.

First step is to go through the company policies to find a suitable one, 
if none are found, you can check with HR regarding this.

If there is no such policy in the company you work , you would have to talk to your supervisor and come up with some sort of solution to the issue.

Comment: +1 - it will widely vary by company. If the current one is helpful in this regard, policies may allow for a sabbatical or a reduction from full-time. If it's relevant to the job, there might be some reimbursement, though usually to qualify for that you need approval before taking the classes or getting the degree to be reimbursed.